# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.mockito.internal.runners.RunnerFactory.createStrict(Ljava/lang/Class;)Lorg/mockito/internal/runners/InternalRunner;

Tags: java, unit-testing, groovy, junit, mockito

I am writing my Junit test cases for Groovy using Mockito jar, but it is giving me following exception:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.mockito.internal.runners.RunnerFactory.createStrict(Ljava/lang/Class;)Lorg/mockito/internal/runners/InternalRunner;
at org.mockito.junit.MockitoJUnitRunner.<init>(MockitoJUnitRunner.java:152)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
at org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.buildRunner(AnnotatedBuilder.java:104)
at org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.runnerForClass(AnnotatedBuilder.java:86)
at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
at org.junit.internal.builders.AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.runnerForClass(AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.java:26)
at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
at org.junit.internal.requests.ClassRequest.getRunner(ClassRequest.java:33)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestLoader.createUnfilteredTest(JUnit4TestLoader.java:84)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestLoader.createTest(JUnit4TestLoader.java:70)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestLoader.loadTests(JUnit4TestLoader.java:43)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:444)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:675)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
```

Below is the jar list that I have:

```
cglib-nodep-2.2.2
javassist-3.19.0-GA
junit-4.12
mockito-all-1.10.19
objenesis-2.5
powermock-mockito-1.6.2-full
```

Below is my code. I have added necessary imports:

```
package test.service
import org.junit.Test
import org.junit.runner.RunWith
import org.mockito.InjectMocks
import org.mockito.Mock
import org.mockito.junit.MockitoJUnitRunner
import static org.mockito.Mockito.when;

@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
class SyncImplTest {

    @InjectMocks
    SyncThreatImpl  fixture;

    @Mock
    RpcConfigurationLoader rpcConfigurationLoader

    @Test
    public void testRpcConfig(){
        RpcApiInfo rpcApiInfo =  new RpcApiInfo();
        when(rpcConfigurationLoader.loadConfiguration()).thenReturn(rpcApiInfo)
    }


}
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

For some reason, your test suite, tries to load the `MockitoJunitRunner` from the  `org.mockito.junit` contained in the Mockito versions >= 2. O. In that version, the line:

```
at org.mockito.junit.MockitoJUnitRunner.<init>(MockitoJUnitRunner.java:152)
```

is doing this:

```
public MockitoJUnitRunner(Class<?> klass) throws InvocationTargetException {
        //by default, StrictRunner is used. We can change that potentially based on feedback from users
        this(new StrictRunner(new RunnerFactory().createStrict(klass), klass));
    }
```

and the RunnerFactory that is loaded here is from version 1.x as `createStrict` has been introduced in Mockito 2.x.

So go through the pom dependency tree and to find what artifact implicitly add the Mockito 2.x dependency to your project and exclude it.

Alternatively.. as a workaround, instead of the `@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)` you can use:

```
@Before
public void init() {
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
}
```

You can also check out this [Mockito cheat sheet](https://www.sourceartists.com/cheat-sheet/mockito) to keep all the standards at hand.

Comment: Your answer has solved a similar issue on a bnd project I am working on.  Thank you

Answer (score 14):

The problem lies within your imports.
Your imports doesn't include import runner replace the following import

```
org.mockito.junit.MockitoJUnitRunner
```

with

```
 org.mockito.runners.MockitoJUnitRunner;
```

Comment: Your solution solves our issue but raises "org.mockito.runners.MockitoJUnitRunner" is deprecated warning. Maciej Kowalski's answer solves problem without any warning.

Answer (score 9):

In Mockito 1.10.19 (which is from 2014), there is no class `org.mockito.junit.MockitoJUnitRunner`. This was introduced later in 2.x. If you really want to use 1.10.19, you should probably use the then correct class `org.mockito.runners.MockitoJUnitRunner` which then should work.

But I would strongly recommend using a newer Mockito version instead. `mockito-all` is simply not the right artifact to depend on anymore. With 2.x this artefact was not maintained anymore.

Comment: I replaced Mockito-all with mockito-core 2.13.0 and worked like a charm

Answer (score 0):

i ran into the same issue with following versions.
In my case there was a `mockito-core` dependency through `org.apache.maven:maven:3.6.3`. So i had to override the dependency.

```
 <version.maven-surefire-plugin>3.0.0-M5</version.maven-surefire-plugin>
 <version.junit-jupiter-engine>5.8.2</version.junit-jupiter-engine>
 <version.mockito-junit-jupiter>4.3.1</version.mockito-junit-jupiter>
```

to check this, you can use: `mvn help:effective-pom -Dverbose=true -Doutput=effective-pom.xml`